# Angular 2.1.0.beta.0: Which router version is compatible?

Tags: angular, angular-routing

Upgrading from Angular 2.0.0 to 2.0.1 was no problem: my web app still runs fine.

Now I want to try 2.1.0.beta.0. However, I cannot find which version I should use for `@angular/router` (and later for `@angular/compiler-cli` for AoT compilation). Any hint is appreciated!

Comment: version 3.0.0 doesn't work?????

Comment: Actually, there is 3.0.1 which is installed when doing `npm -i -S @angular/router`. But I'm wondering whether there is also a beta version, e.g. 3.1.0-beta.0. However, I've no idea where to look for such a beta version.

Comment: check with `npm outdated` command. It will show old and new version.

Answer (score 0):

The answer to my question: `npm show @angular/router@* version` shows all versions of the router module.